# Git seems to be reverting back to previous changes on its own

Tags: git, github

I'm using Git with Rstudio and pushing to Github and I can't quite figure out some of this behavior.

I don't think I can reproduce this, but here's what's happening.

I [committed and pushed to github](https://github.com/tomhiatt/WHO-maps/commit/f12958f902d5b7a17cb39c059aa52b05a2e0c638). Note the green additions on lines 156-159.

I then made other changes and [committed again](https://github.com/tomhiatt/WHO-maps/commit/26068f17fc5a9bffd4dff5586dd8c4a8816fb9b5) and my previous changes were removed (red lines 155-167).

I'm no Git wiz so I couldn't figure how how to revert part of a commit so I just manually added the changes back in with [this commit](https://github.com/tomhiatt/WHO-maps/commit/c3b75afd167121a4b0329213f1a305c5966ef139). (Green lines 156-169)

I can't figure out why this might have reverted by itself and I'm *almost* positive that I didn't delete the lines myself. Is there something I could be inadvertently doing that is causing this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something I could be inadvertently doing that is causing this to happen?

With Git itself, not much: it only takes what it sees in the working tree to add it and commit it.
It should be the RStudio IDE which somehow misfired and removed that part just before the second commit.

The only Git operation which "revert" changes (beside [`git revert`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) itself) is [git reset](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset).

Comment: Okay thinking more on Rstudio, I did open and change this file in a different project than the one under Git. Maybe that is tripping up Rstudio.

Comment: @Tom yes, maybe it didn't adequately detect the file changes, and erase it with the old version it still had loaded.